# How to check whether a bash command is run in background?

Tags: linux, bash

I run an installation command in linux that immediately after hitting enter returns me back to the prompt but continues to install.

Does that mean it is run in the background or does it merely mean there is no print to the stdout?

My final goal is to perform a wait on the command but I can't understand if it's run in background or not.

Comment: How do you know, that it continues to install?

Comment: What is the command that you are executing? are you submitting process in backend using `&` or invoking subshell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really up to you, it depends on the command.
By default you wait for it, but if it wants to "run in the background", it can fork and return to you. You have to find a solution on a per-command basis - it would be best if you had a clearer goal, such as "I want to run `apt install some_app` and wait for it to finish".

Comment: To clarify, there is no way to know if it's running in the background, and works 100% of the time. Need to know which command it is in that case as well.